# Phonegap for Windows Mobile 6.5 and Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, cordova

Did anyone test Phonegap and jQuery Mobile with Windows Mobile 6.5 and Windows Phone 7? If yes, how was it? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap support was only very minimal (experimental?) in Windows Mobile 6.x

PhoneGap support for Windows Phone 7.x is still in it's very early stages. (It was only addded to github.com/phonegap this week.)

Comment: I see that this is your git hub project. What are the main problems about the current WP7 support?

Comment: The main issues are that it's incomplete; only supports Mango (which is still in beta); the entire structure of the code will likely change to bring it in line with the other PhoneGap solutions; and it is poorly documented. Nitobi currently classify WP7Gap as pre-alpa quality.

Comment: so there is no chance on getting the code running on pre mango versions?

Comment: @Johe by all means go ahead and try but the number of workarounds you need for javascript support, not to mention targetting IE7 is more than I'd want to consider. (I've looked. it put me off.) The execution model differences between mango and earlier versions mean that an acceptable (to me) level of polish just isn't possible.

Comment: Matt, did you manage to get jQuery mobile running on WP7? The codeplex widget lib seems to do for simpler apps but I can't get jq mobile working properly...

Comment: I ended up with a "normal" Web App. MS trimmed down the capabilities of browser controls in apps so much, that it was impossible to run my app without rewriting most of the code.